# Information-based function approximation. Series of bits instead of series of real/complex coefficients

Tags: taylor-expansion, fourier-series, approximation, wavelets

There are multiple series and functional bases (e.g. Taylor, Fourier) that allow approximating a function.

In some sense, such approximations associate a function with an infinite sequence of real or complex numbers (e.g. coefficients). Also, there are often theorems that bound the approximation errors for a truncated series.

One problem I have with these approaches is that they use real numbers which contain infinite amount of information.

I'm interested in an approximation technique where the function is associated with an infinite series of bits. Ideally there should be a theorem that bounds the approximation errors for a truncated series of bits.

Are there any information-based approximation methods?

Comment: In what sense can a finite sequence of bits approximate an infinite sequence of bits?

Comment: Good question. But with Taylor/Fourier a finite sequence of numbers can approximate an infinite-dimensional objects (function). Also, a finite sequence of bits can approximate a real number, used in Taylor/Fourier series. Just as one can enumerate rational numbers, one can have a sequence of approximations to a Taylor/Fourier series.

Comment: "In what sense can a finite sequence of bits approximate an infinite sequence of bits?": If the bits are ordered by "significance" (or the amount of error they remove), then truncated sequence of bits can be an approximation to an infinite sequence of bits. Just like 3.1415 is an approximation of Pi.

Comment: OK, so, use (say) Taylor series to identify $f$ with a sequence $a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots$ of reals, identify each real $a_i$ with an infinite sequence $b_{i1},b_{i2},\dots$ of bits, then for each $n$ approximate $f$ with the finite sequence $b_{01},b_{02},b_{11},b_{03},b_{12},b_{21},\dots,b_{n1}$, suitably interpreted.

Comment: Yes. I've hinted at this approach. However the problem is that I'm not sure that the "diagonal" ordering of bits that you've mentioned corresponds to the "significance" ordering and allow for the approximation error bounds. E.g. what if $significance(i, j) = 1/(i + 3j)$ or $1/(i + j^2)$ or $1/(i * j)$ or $1/(i + exp(j))$. A correct `significance(i, j)` would lead to a solution, but I'm not sure the $significance(i, j) = 1/(i+j)$, that your proposal implicitly uses, is the correct one. From another angle, the problem is: What's the best way to encode function approximation around 0 using N bits

Comment: Near zero, the constant term of a Taylor series is more significant than the $x$-term, which is more significant than the $x^2$-term, which is more significant.... Also, the first bit of each coefficient is more significant than the second bit, which is more significant than the third bit, which is more significant....

Comment: Yes. But is 100th bit of a0 more significant than the 1st bit of a1?

Comment: That would probably depend on $f$ (and on how close you are to $x=0$). It's a bit much to expect one size to fit all functions.